# Trying to identify an old 2 x 7 white LEGO plate with a hole in the middle and 4 holes on the side

Tags: part-identification, vintage

Recently someone gave me a huge bunch of old LEGO pieces. Among the parts I found a white 4x6 plate with 4 wheel holes (those red wheels with a metal pin), a hole in the middle and an 2x1 extension on one end. Here's a photo: [image]

I suspect that this part is from somewhere between 1960 and 1980. Can anyone identify it? Which sets may contain it?

Answer (score 9):

This is

[Part# 824 :  Train Base 4 x 7 with Wheels Holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=824#T=C&C=1)

It appears in [2 train sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=824&in=S) from 1966